# Editing a value in a matrix is deleting it

Tags: c++

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, but I am writing a program for a Sudoku game. It takes a file, turns it into a matrix, and prints the board on the screen. Then the user is supposed to be able to edit the game.
My problem is with my edit function. Whenever I try to edit a value on the board it just gets rid of that space.

```
void edit(char sudoku[][9])
{
   char letter;
   int number;
   //these are the coordinates for the board

   int value = 0;
   //this is the entered value for the choosen square

   cout << "What are the coordinates of the square: ";
   cin >> letter >> number;

   letter = toupper(letter); // makes sure the letter is caps

   if (sudoku[letter - 65][number - 1] != ' ')
      // if the coordinates are off the board or already have a value
   {
      cout << "Error: Square \'" << letter << number
           << "\' is invalid."
           << endl;
  }
   else
   {
      cout << "What is the value at \'" << letter << number
           << "\': ";
      cin >> value;

      if (value > 9 || value < 1)
         //if the value is invalid
      {
         cout << "ERROR: Value \'" << value
              << "\'in square \'" << letter << number
              << "\' is invalid\n";
      }
      cout << endl;

      sudoku[letter - 65][number - 1] = value;
      //set the square = the entered value
   }
   return;
```

this is the board before the edit:

```
   A B C D E F G H I
1  7 2 3|     |1 5 9
2  6    |3   2|    8
3  8    |  1  |    2
   -----+-----+-----
4    7  |6 5 4|  2
5      4|2   7|3
6    5  |9 3 1|  4
   -----+-----+-----
7  5    |  7  |    3
8  4    |1   3|    6
9  9 3 2|     |7 1 4
```

And after:

```
What are the coordinates of the square: b2
What is the value at 'B2': 3

   A B C D E F G H I
1  7 2 3|     |1 5 9
2  6   |3   2|    8
3  8    |  1  |    2
   -----+-----+-----
4    7  |6 5 4|  2
5      4|2   7|3
6    5  |9 3 1|  4
   -----+-----+-----
7  5    |  7  |    3
8  4    |1   3|    6
9  9 3 2|     |7 1 4
```

so the only change is that a space was deleted after the edit.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer to use `'A'` to 65 in `letter - 65`. The intent of the code is more obvious and more resistant (but not immune to. See EBCDIC) to different character encodings.

Comment: Oliver, this question is still listed as unanswered. If my answer wasn't clear, please ask and I'll try to improve it.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
sudoku[letter - 65][number - 1] = value;
```

puts the ASCII value 0-9 in your `sudoku` array that consists of `char`s. These ASCII characters are often invisible or have some other special meaning, like beeping or tabulating.

You need to add the value of `'0'` to it to make it show up ok:

```
sudoku[letter - 'A'][number - 1] = value + '0';
```

and replace magic numbers like 65 with a character literal, like `'A'`.